# Validating latex mathematical expressions using Sympy

Tags: python, latex, sympy

How do I check if a LaTeX str is valid or not without saving the image?

For example:

`['-2<y<-1', '\lim_{c\to1^{+}}e^{\ln{(6+c^{\cot{c}})}}', '\lim_{c\to1}6\tan{c}', '3_{6}\times 4_{6}+1_{6}=13_{10}=21_{6}', 'wx+yz']`

`sympy.preview` can generate every string even if it is just some random charcaters.

`sympy.parse_latex` cannot catch many valid equation such as `'( 4 , 5 , 1 )'`

I put those rejected lines from parse_latex [here](https://arachnoid.com/latex/) and it is renderable. So I'm not sure if it's a good function to use.

Comment: Evidently what you consider to be "valid latex" is broader than what `sympy` does.  I don't know if anyone can help beyond what's documented: https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/parsing.html#experimental-mathrm-latex-parsing